# Función que no devuelve el valor

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo la siguiente función en R que no devuelve ningún valor, y creo que es porque estoy usando `floor()` para obtener la parte entera de un decimal.

```
cambiarEscala <- function(x) {
    # Calculo de la puntuación de corrección equivalente en función del número entero de la puntuación
    if (floor(x) == 1) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 1
    }
    if (floor(x) == 2) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 2
    }
    if (floor(x) == 3) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 3
    }
    if (floor(x) == 4) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 4
    }
    if (floor(x) == 5) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 5
    }
}
```

Si utilizo `cambiarEscala(1.9)` la función no devuelve nada y debería devolver 2.25, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Respuesta

Lo que sucede es que `R` evalua cada bloque condicional y al final no hay nada que retornar...

Para cortar o romper estos bloques condicionales es necesario usar el statement `if... else if...` cosa que `R` devolverá el valor correspondiente:

```
cambiarEscala <- function(x) {
    # Calculo de la puntuación de corrección equivalente en función del número entero de la puntuación
    if (floor(x) == 1) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 1
    }
    else if (floor(x) == 2) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 2
    }
    else if (floor(x) == 3) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 3
    }
    else if (floor(x) == 4) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 4
    }
    else if (floor(x) == 5) {
        (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 5
    }
}

cambiarEscala(1.9)
```

### Extendiendo Respuesta

Como mencioné es necesario indicarle a la función `cambiarEscalar` en que momento detenerse, para ellos se puede emplear la palabra reservada en cada `if`, pero la expresión debe estar encapsulada en paréntesis:

```
#R version 3.4.4 
cambiarEscala <- function(x) {
    # Calculo de la puntuación de corrección equivalente en función del número entero de la puntuación
    if (floor(x) == 1) {
        return ((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 1)
    }
    if (floor(x) == 2) {
        return ((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 2)
    }
    if (floor(x) == 3) {
        return ((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 3)
    }
    if (floor(x) == 4) {
        return ((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 4)
    }
    if (floor(x) == 5) {
        return ((x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 5)
    }

}

cambiarEscala(1.9)
```

### Consideración Final

Si se observa cada expresión a evaluar en el `if` `(floor(x) == n)` es el igual a cada uno de los sumandos al final de la expresión `(x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + n` para todo `n` menor e igual a 5 entero y mayor a cero:

Entonces podría quedar así la función final:

```
#R version 3.4.4 
cambiarEscala <- function(x) {

    # Condiciones
    n <- floor(x)
    rango <- ( (n >= 1) & (n <= 5) )
    
    # Calculo de la puntuación de corrección equivalente en función del número entero de la puntuación
    if ( rango ) {
        (x - n) * 2.5 + n
    }
    else {
        cat("fuera de rango")
    }

}

cambiarEscala(1.9)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ampliada respuesta, me ha venido genial.

Answer (score 1):

No retorna nada por que no estas indicándole que retorne algo en concreto, puedes guardar el resultado en una variable y, para luego retornarla al final de todos los if

```
cambiarEscala <- function(x) {
  # Calculo de la puntuación de corrección equivalente en función del número entero de la puntuación
  if (floor(x) == 1) {
    y = (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 1
  }
  if (floor(x) == 2) {
    y = (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 2
  }
  if (floor(x) == 3) {
    y = (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 3
  }
  if (floor(x) == 4) {
    y = (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 4
  }
  if (floor(x) == 5) {
    y = (x - floor(x)) * 2.5 + 5
  }
  return(y)
}

cambiarEscala(1.9)
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta!!!